# How to delete attendance record with specified userid via zkemkeeper

Tags: c#, api, sdk, interop, biometrics

I m using zkemkeeper.dll to download attendance record from biometric device. After download i cleared attendance record from device. By using code below:

```
    private void btnBeep_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      int MachineNo = 1;
      bool rs = axCZKEM1.ClearGLog(MachineNo);
      axCZKEM1.RefreshData(MachineNo); 
      if (rs){
            Recfound = 0;
      }
    }
```

It working fine and attendance log cleared successfully. 
But now i want to clear attendance log by specifying userid for which data i already downloaded. Is there any method provided by API to clear specific user attendance log ?

Answer (score 0):

First thing, You cannot download the attendance logs specific to the user id. You might have used one of *ReadGeneralLogData, GetAllGLogData, GetGeneralLogData, GetGeneralLogDataStr* and *GetGeneralExtLogData* to download the attendance logs. They dont accept the user id as input.

second thing, you cannot clear the log specific to the user id. If you want to clear the log, everything to be cleared.

You need to make sure that you read all the attendance logs before calling the clear log.

Answer (score -1):

You can clear a single user using the function:

```
DeleteEnrollData([in] long dwMachineNumber, [in] long dwEnrollNumber, [in] long dwEMachineNumber, [in] long dwBackupNumber)
```

Comment: This Deletes Fingerprint template of enrolled user. and not the attendace log of the user